# How to properly initialize an ArrayList of an ArrayList of Integers read from input file

Tags: java, regex, arraylist, multidimensional-array, integer

I need to parse an input file with this format. The input file can be of any size, so I decided to go with Lists rather than arrays. I need to store it an array after the data is parsed. It represents RGB values. E.g. this snippet is a 2x2 pixel image.

[251,255,128],[132,244,121]
[125,156,155],[157,200,090]

public class RGBFileReader {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename;
    filename = args[0];
    new RGBFileReader().ReadRGBfile(filename);
} // end main method block

// declare the class constructor, pass filename parameter and initialize variables
public void ReadRGBfile (String filename) {
    int rowCount = 0;
    int columnCount = 0;
    int columnIndex = 0;

    //2D List = ArrayList of an ArrayList of Integers. ArrayList stores Objects not "ints"!
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> rgbArrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    try {
        //confirm current working directory for I/O files
        System.out.println("parsing input file at path: " + new File(".").getAbsoluteFile()+ filename);

        // pass the path to the file as a parameter 
        File file = new File("input/" + filename); 
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(file);

        // pattern match to sequence of comma delimited integers inside square brackets: [+/-int,+/-int,+/-int]    
        // -? = once or not at all, and minus sign handles negative numbers (although not strictly needed in this context)
        String patternToMatch = "\\[(-?\\d+),(-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\]";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternToMatch);

        // [\\d] = any digit, note need a second backslash to escape first backslash which is a java escape character
        // +     = 1 or more occurrences
        String innerpatternToMatch = "(\\d+)";
        Pattern innerpattern = Pattern.compile(innerpatternToMatch);

        while (myScanner.hasNextLine()) { // while loop to scan each line of input file
            ArrayList<Integer> singleRow = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            columnIndex = 0;
            System.out.println("rowCount: " + rowCount);
            String line = myScanner.nextLine();
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

            while (matcher.find()) { // outer while to parse groups of brackets

                System.out.println("columnCount: " + columnCount);
                String outerline = matcher.group();
                System.out.println("outerline: " + outerline);
                Matcher innermatcher = innerpattern.matcher(outerline);

                while (innermatcher.find()) { // inner while to parse triplets within brackets
                    String innerline = innermatcher.group();
                    System.out.println("innerline: " + innerline);
                    singleRow.add(Integer.valueOf(innermatcher.group())); //add triplets one at a time to inner List "oneRow"
                    System.out.println("singleRow = " + singleRow);
                    columnIndex++;
                } //end inner inner while
                columnCount = columnIndex;

            } // end outer while
            rgbArrayList.add(singleRow);  // add the oneRow of triplets, to the outer List "twodimArrayList"
            System.out.println("rgbArrayList dump using toString(): " + rgbArrayList.toString());
            System.out.println("\n");
            rowCount++;

        } // end scanner while loop
        myScanner.close();
        System.out.println("scanner is closed...");

    } // end Try block
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not open RGB input file: check it exists, is in the file path, or has correct format.");
    } //end catch block

    //sanity check for correct values of rowCount and columnCount
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("rowCount: " + rowCount);
    System.out.println("columnCount: " + columnCount);

    // Parsing of input file complete, now declare int[][] array
    int [][] rgbArray = new int [rowCount][columnCount];

    // check for expected values properly stored in ArrayList 
    System.out.println("\n"); 
    System.out.println("List<Integer> rgbArrayList values using iterator" );
    Iterator<ArrayList<Integer>> iterator = rgbArrayList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }

    //Initialize the int [][] Array using values from the ArrayList
    System.out.println("\n");
    for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++) {
            rgbArray[row][col] = rgbArrayList.get(row).get(col).intValue();
        } // end inner for loop
    } // end outer for loop

    System.out.println("rgbArray values"); 
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rgbArray[i]));
    } // end inner loop

} // end method ReadRGBfile
```

} // end class

Comment: why do you not simplify this to use an List of `java.awt.Color` ?

Comment: You will get help on this site much faster if you can highlight the few lines of code where the actual problem is.  If you _can't_ do that, then maybe you should try stepping through your code with a debugger to see exactly where it is breaking.

Comment: I was not aware of java.awt.Color. I checked it out and its looks useful.

Comment: Apologies after the fact if the specific ask was not clear. I've attempted to be more specific in my latest comment.

Comment: I've edited the post hopefully to take the message off hold. If not satisfactory, welcome feedback on to make it conform to the forum guidelines. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really such a thing as a 2D ArrayList. You are creating a List of Lists, which means each element of the outer List must be a new `ArrayList<Integer>` and all inner Lists do not need to be the same size as one another. Try moving your `singleRow` declaration down inside of the while loop and removing `singleRow.clear();`

As a side note, it isn't necessary to use an index when you add to a List. `twodimArrayList.add(singleRow);` will add to the end of the List.

Comment: As suggested, I moved the ArrayList<Integer> singleRow = new ArrayList<Integer>(); declaration into the Scanner while loop and now produces the correct result (updated code in my edit). I'ts not clear to me why that fixed the problem in the previous version of the code, where the last row of the sample input file was input into the integer array twice.